# Modify the given program to use a loop to output

Tags: python-3.x

This program outputs a downwards facing arrow composed of a rectangle and a right triangle. The arrow dimensions are defined by user specified arrow base height, arrow base width, and arrow head width.

1. Modify the given program to use a loop to output an arrow base of height arrow_base_height.
   (1 pt)
2. Modify the given program to use a loop to output an arrow base of width arrow_base_width.
   (1 pt)
3. Modify the given program to use a loop to output an arrow head of width arrow_head_width.
   (2 pts)
4. Modify the given program to only accept an arrow head width that is larger than the arrow base width. Use a loop to continue prompting the user for an arrow head width until the value is larger than the arrow base width.
   (1 pt)

Code:

```
while arrow_head_width <= arrow_base_width:
    print ('Enter arrow head width: ')
    arrow_head_width = int(input())
```

Example output for arrow_base_height = 5, arrow_base_width = 2, and arrow_head_width = 4:

```
Enter arrow base height: 5
Enter arrow base width: 2
Enter arrow head width: 4
**
**
**
**
**
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: while arrow_head_width <= arrow_base_width:
    print ('Enter arrow head width: ')
    arrow_head_width = int(input())

Comment: Enter arrow base height: 5
Enter arrow base width: 2
Enter arrow head width: 4
**
**
**
**
**
****
***
**
*

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
arrow_head_height = int(input('Enter Head Height'))
arrow_base_height = int(input('Enter Base Height'))
arrow_base_width = int(input('Enter Base Width'))

while arrow_base_height > 0:
    print(arrow_base_width*'*')
    arrow_base_height -= 1
    if arrow_base_height == 0:
        for i in range(arrow_head_height,0,-1):
            print(i*'*')
```

Comment: This is what I am getting.

Comment: Enter Head HeightTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    arrow_head_height = int(input('Enter Head Height'))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: This error occur when you are using input() with python version lower than 3.x

Comment: SO just take input as per your python version

Comment: arrow_base_height = int(input('Enter arrow base height::\n '))
arrow_base_width = int(input('Enter arrow base width:\n '))
arrow_head_width = int(input('Enter arrow head width:\n' ))

while arrow_head_width <= arrow_base_width: 
    arrow_head_width =int(input('Enter arrow head width:\n '))
print('')

for i in range (arrow_base_height):
    i = ('*' * arrow_base_width)
    print(i)
for j in range (arrow_head_width): 
    j = '*' * arrow_head_width
    print (j)
    arrow_head_width -= 1